# Fetching from background thread with Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I want to fetch my data from a background thread to improve performance. How can I achieve this? I couldn't find help anywhere.

Currently, I am fetching my data like so:

```
do {
    let items = try mainContext.fetch(Item.fetchRequest())
    return items
} catch { ... }
```

From my understanding, I can't run the above code on a background thread, since the main context is bound to the main thread. So this would not be possible:

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    do {
        let items = try mainContext.fetch(Item.fetchRequest())
        completion(items)
    } catch { ... }
}
```

So I have tried to do that on a background context like so:

```
let backgroundContext = container.newBackgroundContext()
backgroundContext.parent = mainContext

backgroundContext.perform {
    do {
        let items = try backgroundContext.fetch(Item.fetchRequest())
        DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(items) }
    } catch { ... }
}
```

But unfortunately, this seems not to work either.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> From my understanding, I can't run the above code on a background thread, since the main context is bound to the main thread.

It's not so much that a context is "bound" to a thread, it's that you need to make sure that operations on a given context are properly serialized. So you could pass your main context into the background operation and use it for the fetch, but you'd need to avoid using the main context from the main thread until that background operation was done. That kind of coordination is easy to get wrong, so it's good to avoid.

> let backgroundContext = container.newBackgroundContext()
> backgroundContext.parent = mainContext

This should work, and being able to operate in the background and share the results is one reason that the managed object context has a `parent`. However, the changes you make in `backgroundContext` won't be visible in `mainContext` until you save them. There's no call to `save()` in the code you've shown, so that may be part of the problem.

> I want to fetch my data from a background thread to improve performance.

Before you go too far down the path you're on, make sure that you really need to do this. Core Data can be *very* fast, and since you usually can't display a ton of data all at the same time it often doesn't make sense to fetch all the results at once. If you fetch a smaller number of objects, you might get the performance improvement you're looking for without having to bother with background operations.

Comment: Awesome, saving it worked! But as you've mentioned, since I have at most around 20 entries to be fetched... I should not worry about background operations. Thanks a lot, this was very informative and greatly increased my understanding.

Comment: This helped me a LOT. After hours of guess & check coding, followed by more time researching correct multi-threaded CoreData implementations -- You've got me thinking outside that box and realizing that the amount of objects I'm fetching doesn't really need to be run in the background for performance sake. Lifesaver, cheers.